# Giant TCR advanced ( 2016 ) Carbon Seatpost

Tags: bike-fit, seatpost, giant

I have been considering making a foray into road bikes and ended up picking up a pretty pristine Giant TCR advanced 2016 bike for a bargain. I bought a size M and ended up figuring out that I actually needed a size M/L.

https://bikeinsights.com/compare?geometries=5d1434e58f568e0017f135bc,5d1434e58f568e0017f135bd,  (scroll down to see comparison)

I couldn't figure out as I am used to steel tourers and more into commuting until now. I have the seatpost set to almost the cutoff height. I still feel that it should be 15~20mm larger for me to be at my most efficient.

I looked up the seatpost, it seems like a proprietary product.

https://www.giant-bicycles.com/gb/giant-variant-advanced-carbon-seatpost

The standard length seems to be 375mm. I figured out that if I get a 400mm seatpost, it'd be good enough for me, and I should be able to ride just fine. However, I am not able to find the seatpost, they seem to be out of stock, since the newer version has a different seatpost.

Are there any aftermarket brands (even from aliexpress) which would be a suitable replacement? Is there anything else that I can do to increase the height,like a different saddle for example. Or is this a lost cause?

Is there anything else that I can do such as changing the stem, to make the bike fit me better ?

Comment: I looked on the 'bay to see if there were anything that would work there but came up empty (a few 375-380 mm offerings, but nothing longer).  As the owner of the 2015 TCR Advanced, I would complement you on your taste in bike (love my TCR), but as Criggie answered, you are probably out of luck getting your size M to fit.  A bike that does not fit is not one you would want to ride, and could be a safety concern as well.  I wish it could have been a fit for you, but the best deal in the world is only good if it fits, and you feel comfortable riding it.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly if you need a longer seatpost, there's not a lot of other options.

It is possible to get longer crank-arms, but that's not cheap and you also increase the risk of pedal strike on the ground when turning/leaning.  Additionally this lifts your other leg higher at the same time, which may feel odd.

Riding with the seatpost near, at, or above the minimum insertion line is a recipe for frame damage - I've killed multiple frames from doing this.

Your best fix is a much longer seatpost, or bite the bullet and sell/return the bike, to buy the size you really need.  Do try and test-ride any replacement bike before you commit.